# My SQL script is okay but I can't write this SQL script in Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel-6

```
SELECT appointmentDate 
     , appiontmentTime
     , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) name
          FROM users ta 
          JOIN appointment u 
            ON u.salesperson = ta.id   
         WHERE u.appiontmentTime = appt.appiontmentTime 
           AND u.appointmentDate = appt.appointmentDate
        ) usersname  
  FROM appointment appt 
 WHERE appointmentDate BETWEEN "2020-05-01" AND "2020-05-31" 
 GROUP 
    BY appointmentDate
     , appiontmentTime
```

Comment: What is an ap *pio* ntment?

Comment: "appointment" is table name

Comment: Ok. what is an ap *pio* ntmentTime

Comment: appointmentDate,  appiontmentTime is field name of appointment table

Comment: Say goodnight Gracie

Comment: Hi @wplover! Welcome to StackOverflow. To better help you, it would be helpful to understand how you are trying to run this query within Laravel-6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a reason, why you need a subquery here. I think the following query should return the same result:

```
SELECT a.appointmentDate 
     , a.appiontmentTime
     , GROUP_CONCAT(u.name) name
FROM appointment a
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = a.salesperson
WHERE a.appointmentDate BETWEEN "2020-05-01" AND "2020-05-31" 
GROUP 
    BY a.appointmentDate
     , a.appiontmentTime
```

Using laravels query builder it would be:

```
$data = DB::table('appointment as a')
    ->leftJoin('users as u', 'u.id',  '=', 'a.salesperson')
    ->whereBetween('a.appointmentDate', ['2020-05-01', '2020-05-31'])
    ->groupBy('a.appointmentDate', 'a.appiontmentTime')
    ->select('a.appointmentDate', 'a.appiontmentTime')
    ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(u.name) as name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I am getting the result using laravel  query builder, but not the perfect result. Can you give me your email address. i want to send my screen shoot by for proper explanation

Comment: No emails - sorry.

Comment: May i want to give you my email. can you replay i my inbox ?

Comment: As I wrote.. No emails in neither way. You can edit your question and make it more clear. Add some sample data and expected result. Also verify that your initial query from the question really returns what you want.

Comment: Please check the https://prnt.sc/syp7rv. Hoped by this you could understand